# How to get only date and time from utc time in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

i want to convert utc time to ist time , im getting time like this. i want to remove  "GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

> Thu Jul 19 2018 18:06:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Expected result

Jul 19 2018 18:06:14 or 19/7/2018 06:06 PM

sample data

> 2018-07-19T16:36:21.065Z

code

```
function UtcToIst(data) {
    var dt = new Date(data);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: To [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)!

Comment: @tadman He wants to do the opposite: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: @JustinPearce I'm just giving a place to start, not a concrete solution. If you want to provide a full answer, by all means.

Comment: @tadman No, no, I agree. The documentation is a great place to start!

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the moment.js library (https://momentjs.com/)? This would make your task very easy.

Comment: i have got the solution and updated it in my answer section , can u plz check it, whether im right or wrong

Answer (score 2):

I achieved it in the following way. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

```
var data = '2018-07-19T16:36:21.065Z';

function UtcToIst(data) {
    var dt = new Date(data);
    return dt;
}

var updDate = UtcToIst(data).toLocaleDateString();
var updTime = UtcToIst(data).toLocaleTimeString();
var updDateTime = updDate + ", " + updTime;

console.log(updDateTime); // 7/19/2018, 9:36:21 AM
```